# 500 internal error & permission denied after following the centos 7 installation tutorial

Tags: ckan

After following the "install ckan on centos 7" tutorial and making a few modifications (like replace pass with postgres password and replacing domain name with my own ip), I have got the postgresql and solr (started using tomcat, on port 8080) up and running.

In the development.ini, I specified solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/ckan-schema-2.3, which should be fine I think.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/
Response:
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="solr-admin.css">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico"></link>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico"></link>
<title>Welcome to Solr</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Solr!</h1>
<a href="."><img border="0" align="right" height="78" width="142" src="admin/solr_small.png" alt="Solr"/></a>
<a href="ckan-schema-2.3/admin/">Admin ckan-schema-2.3</a><br/>
<a href="ckan-schema-1.4/admin/">Admin ckan-schema-1.4</a><br/>
</body>
</html>

curl -s 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/admin/cores?wt=json&indent=true'
{
 "responseHeader":{
  "status":0,
  "QTime":6},
 "status":{
  "ckan-schema-2.3":{
    "name":"ckan-schema-2.3",
    "instanceDir":"/usr/share/solr/core0/",
    "dataDir":"/var/lib/solr/data/core0/",
    "startTime":"2017-10-12T02:13:14.678Z",
    "uptime":129083472,
    "index":{
     "numDocs":0,
     "maxDoc":0,
     "version":1507774394724,
     "optimized":false,
     "current":true,
     "hasDeletions":false,
     "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory:org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/var/lib/solr/data/core0/index",
     "lastModified":"2017-10-12T02:13:14Z"}},
  "ckan-schema-1.4":{
    "name":"ckan-schema-1.4",
    "instanceDir":"/usr/share/solr/core1/",
    "dataDir":"/var/lib/solr/data/core1/",
    "startTime":"2017-10-12T02:13:15.599Z",
    "uptime":129082552,
    "index":{
     "numDocs":0,
     "maxDoc":0,
     "version":1507774395601,
     "optimized":false,
     "current":true,
     "hasDeletions":false,
     "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory:org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@/var/lib/solr/data/core1/index",
     "lastModified":"2017-10-12T02:13:15Z"}}}}

curl -s 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/ckan-schema-2.3/admin/ping?wt=json&indent=true'
{
 "responseHeader":{
  "status":0,
  "QTime":8,
  "params":{
    "echoParams":"all",
    "q":"solrpingquery",
    "qt":"standard",
    "echoParams":"all",
    "wt":"json",
    "indent":"true"}},
 "status":"OK"}
```

However, when I accessed CKAN in both remote browser and localhost, I got an internal server error (500).

After examining the ckan.error.log, I found the following error message, which I think might be a connection problem between CKAN (2.4.1) and Solr (1.4.1).

The link to the tutorial I followed: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/How-to-install-CKAN-2.x-on-CentOS-7

```
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185548 2017] [:error] [pid 2438] 2017-10-12 02:42:57,184 ERROR [ckan.lib.search.common] [Errno 13] Permission denied
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185581 2017] [:error] [pid 2438] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185584 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/common.py", line 51, in is_available
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185586 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]     conn.query("*:*", rows=1)
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185588 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 703, in query
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185590 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]     return self.select(*args, **params)
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185592 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 798, in __call__
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185594 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]     xml = self.raw(**params)
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185596 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 823, in raw
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185598 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]     rsp = conn._post(self.selector, request, conn.form_headers)
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185600 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 646, in _post
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185602 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]     self._reconnect()
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185603 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 625, in _reconnect
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185605 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]     self.conn.connect()
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185607 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 807, in connect
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185609 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]     self.timeout, self.source_address)
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185610 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185612 2017] [:error] [pid 2438]     raise err
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185614 2017] [:error] [pid 2438] error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.185715 2017] [:error] [pid 2438] 2017-10-12 02:42:57,185 WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.222342 2017] [:error] [pid 2438] [remote 100.36.143.168:224] mod_wsgi (pid=2438): Target WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.222360 2017] [:error] [pid 2438] [remote 100.36.143.168:224] mod_wsgi (pid=2438): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'.
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.222381 2017] [:error] [pid 2438] [remote 100.36.143.168:224] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.222396 2017] [:error] [pid 2438] [remote 100.36.143.168:224]   File "/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi", line 9, in <module>
[Thu Oct 12 02:42:57.222449 2017] [:error] [pid 2438] [remote 100.36.143.168:224]     application = loadapp('config:%s' % config_filepath)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a permissions problem creating the socket connection. This might be to do with SELinux. See if SELinux enforcement is switched on:

```
getenforce
```

If it is, you'll need to read up on permissions for the socket.

Comment: Great! After I temporarily disabled the SELinux and specified the ckan.storage_path (the error log told me to), now I can see the CKAN in the browser, but without css rendering. The error log only gives me this: [Fri Oct 13 16:40:23.915712 2017] [:error] [pid 19360] 2017-10-13 16:40:23,915 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  / render time 0.042 seconds. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, good - please mark this as the solution then. Start a separate question for CSS stuff. The errors will be in the browser console or network tab for this one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, please see the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774582/everything-works-fine-with-ckan-through-vpn-but-when-accessed-from-the-public

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this error message is the key one:

```
Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
```

Those CKAN Centos install instructions configure CKAN with:

```
solr_url=http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/ckan-schema-2.3
```

and when CKAN tries to run a SOLR query using that URL, it's failing. Specifically it can't connect to 127.0.0.1:8080, which usually means nothing is listening i.e. probably SOLR is not running. So this sounds like a pure SOLR problem, not a CKAN one.

First check that SOLR is running and responding on its main admin interface:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/
```

Now check that that the SOLR core needed by CKAN is configured:

```
curl -s 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/admin/cores?wt=json&indent=true'
```

A CKAN SOLR core looks like this:

```
"ckan":{
  "name":"ckan",
  "instanceDir":"/etc/solr/ckan/",
  "dataDir":"/var/lib/solr/data/",
  "startTime":"2017-10-13T10:32:01.3Z",
  "uptime":1805340,
  "index":{
    "numDocs":50,
    "maxDoc":52,
    "version":1490867603581,
    "segmentCount":9,
    "current":true,
    "hasDeletions":true,
    "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory:org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory@/var/lib/solr/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@4b3e213f",
    "lastModified":"2017-10-13T10:44:47Z"}}
```

That Centos install guide gives you two cores, although you only need the later one - ignore the old schema-1.4 one. Check that the schema-2.3 one's name (the first 2 lines of the core) is set to: `ckan-schema-2.3`, as per the last bit in your `solr_url` (I have just `ckan` in the example above, which is the default).

You can check the status of a SOLR core like this:

```
curl -s 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ckan-schema-2.3/admin/ping?wt=json&indent=true'
```

Check it ends with: `"status":"OK"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The solr has been running ok. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I've fixed the url to match your install instructions. I've added more diagnostics commands. Please run these and paste the output into your question.

Comment: I have checked all three things you mentioned and updated the question. Seems to me Solr is running well. It is possible the key message is "[ckan.lib.search.common] [Errno 13] Permission denied" or "Target WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.". Thanks!